# Lock row for very large time interval on SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have to lock a row for a long period of time, for example an hour. My code look like this:

```
with get_orm().session() as session:
    instance = session.query(Model).filter(Model.id=1).with_for_update().first()
    very_slow_process() # duration: one hour
    instance.retry = instance.retry +1
```

I get the error:

> Lost connection to MySQL server during query

I expected to block the row, and one hour aft update the row, and after that close the transaction.

Comment: What does `show variables like 'wait_timeout'` return?

Comment: wait_timeout is 28800 . I think that is 8 hours